# Grid filled with +1 or -1 is adjusted such that each cell is the product of its adjacent squares

Tags: probability, combinatorics, matrices, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In a 9x9 grid, we fill each square with either +1 or -1. We define an **adjustment** of the numbers in the grid as follows:

*1. For each square, we calculate the product of its 4 adjacent squares (fewer than 4 for edge or corner squares).*

*2. We replace the value of each square with this corresponding product.*

Show if the following statement is correct:
'**For any initial statement of the grid, after a sufficient (finite) number of adjustments, all the grid becomes +1.**'

If correct, prove it; otherwise, give an example.

I played around with this in Python, and realized that the pattern repeats itself after every 12 iterations of the adjustment, for any starting setup, and so the statement is definitely false. However, I am unable to prove this mathematically.

Comment: Are you trying to prove the falsity of the original statement mathematically or the specific claim that all grids repeat after 12 iterations?

Comment: I am trying to prove the falsity of the statement, I just happened to find out that the grid repeats after 12 iterations.

Comment: So, you found a particular grid which gets in a cycle of length $12$? Then, simply writing down that grid is a sufficient disproof. Anyone who sees the grid can trivially compute the next $12$ stages, and verify that you end up in a cycle, so that is all the proof needs.

Comment: I am not convinced that every starting pattern repeats after 12 adjustments- are you certain?

Comment: @MikeEarnest This question popped up in an exam I had taken, and the approximate time limit for this question was approximately 25 mins. It would have been very tough, though not impossible, to start with a random setup (or a simple pattern) and run the iteration 12 times, to realise it repeats. I was trying to find the solution the examiner intended, hoping it wasn't just brute force.

Comment: @Sal Although the initial setup does not repeat in most cases, the following patterns after consecutive adjustments seem to cycle. I noticed that the 4th, 16th, 28th, etc. iterations all result in the same grid pattern.

Comment: I've put some thought in to the "invariant" strategy as @Sal suggested. You might be able to make an invariant by taking the product of the entries in some subset of the squares in the grid. If you call the squares in your subset "important" squares, then you get the following rules for what squares can be important:-Every unimportant square must  be adjacent to an even number of important squares, and every important square must be adjacent to an odd number of important square (you might want to check that these are sufficient but I'm pretty sure they're necessary).

Comment: On further thought though, that doesn't help much because exactly the same  requirements would give you a grid that get's adjusted back to itself, so the whole "look for grids that eventually go back to themselves" thing works more generally

Comment: What might help is the following: Start with $A\in \mathbb \{-1,1\} ^{9\times 9}$. Now map each cell of $A$ as follows: $1\mapsto 0, -1\mapsto 1$. If we now interpret $A$ as a matrix over $\mathbb F_2$, then one adjustment step consists of replacing the value of each cell of $A$ with the sum of its neighbor cells. With that, the adjustment rule can be written as a matrix $M$ over $\mathbb F_2$, and the statement now is that $M$ is nilpotent.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let A be
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
  1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
  1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
  1 &\color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} &\color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
  1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & 1
\end{array}

The grid does not change at all.

Answer (score 6):

The statement is false.

A counterexample is

$$
A=\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
  1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 \\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
\color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1
\end{array}
$$

This becomes

$$B=
\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
\color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} \\\hline
1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
\color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} \\\hline
1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \end{array}
$$ which becomes $A$.

---

To find a counterexample of $9\times 9$, I first tried to find a counterexample of $4\times 4$, and got the following counterexample :

$$
C=\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  1 & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}
$$

This becomes
$$
D=\begin{array}{c|c|c|c}
  1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 \\\hline
 1 & \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{array}
$$
which becomes $C$.

From $C$, I got $A$.

Comment: Nice answer. I think, however, that OP is asking about a way to validate this without trial and error, perhaps using invariants like in the [sliding puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/15_puzzle?useskin=vector)

Answer (score 3):

One more example. Let $a_{i, j} = -1$ if $i \in \{1, 3, 5, 7, 9\}$ and $a_{i, j} = 1$ if $i \in \{2, 4, 6, 8\}$.

A=\begin{array}{c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c}
  \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} \\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
\color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1}\\\hline
 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
 \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1} & \color{red}{-1}
\end{array}

The idea is that the even rows do not change, and the odd rows are changing separately. We only need to check that row of nine -1's enters period 6 after 3 iterations. Although this proof still requires some calculations.